# Limited choices in a rdf:property

Tags: rdf, semantics, ontology, owl, rdfs

I'm making an Ontology that describes programming languages, but I have the following problem: a language can have strong or weak typing, and I need to limit my schema to these two options... so, how can I do that?

Here's a sample of my schema:

```
:Language a rdfs:Class .

:typing a rdf:Propery ;
    rdfs:domain :Language ;
    rdfs:range ? .
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with the answer posted by Eduardo Silva. A functional property can have only one *value* from the range of the function. It can be used multiple times, but an OWL reasoner can make some entailments from those triples. For example, if you have some individual `example:x1` and a functional property `:p`, and you see in your data:

```
example:x1 :p :foo .
example:x1 :p :bar .
```

then you are entitled to infer that `:foo` and `:bar` *must be the same individual*, since otherwise the functional nature of `:p` would be violated. Alternatively, if you know by some other means that `:foo` and `:bar` are different individuals, then, given the two additional triples above, your OWL model is inconsistent.

In other words, it would be fine to have two values for `test:typing` on some resource, as long as you then entail that the two type schemes denoted are in fact the same. Which probably isn't what you want. Moreover, there's nothing to stop a triple store containing a *new* value for `test:typing` which wasn't mentioned in the original range description. For example:

```
:ruby a test:Language ; 
    test:typing test:duckTyping.
```

This is *not* inconsistent with `test:typing` being a functional property.

To restrict the range of a property to be one of a certain enumeration of values, what you actually want is an OWL [enumerated class](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#EnumeratedClass). For example:

```
test:typing
    a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:domain test:Language ;
    rdfs:range [
        owl:oneOf ( test:strongTyping test:weakTyping )
    ].
```

The extension (set of admissible values) of an enumerated class is exactly the given collection of individuals. No others are allowed.

Comment: Hello Ian... great answer, I'll look the w3c docs with more attention, but, you're right, I need those constraints, like owl:oneOf can do. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ian, I do see the point of using the owl:oneOf. However, I still struggle to see the problem of using FunctionalProperty, as each language has only one type (assuming this is a strict requirement). According to the specification: "a property that can have only one (unique) value y for each instance x, i.e. there cannot be two distinct values y1 and y2 such that the pairs (x,y1) and (x,y2) are both instances of this property.". My question is when can we use functional property then? (also, can we grant that owl:oneOf is not specified twice for the same individual?)

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. As I read the OP's question, he wanted to be able to model that the range of `test:typing` contained a fixed set of distinct identifiers and no others. Declaring the property as functional may well be useful and a good idea, but doesn't solve either of those problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution can be to define a "functional property", which is a property that limits the "range" to one member of the class (e.g.: a Person hasGender Gender, where gender can be Female or Male - only one).

This in owl would look something like this (quickly made in Protege):

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&test;typing">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&test;Language"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&test;Type"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

(then Type, would have sub-classes: strong and weak).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read the OWL documentation about owl:FunctionalPropery and it looks exactly what I need... one question: are you from Brazil?

Comment: This is not the correct use of `owl:FunctionalProperty`. See my alternative answer.